# Double header dataframe, sumif (possibly groupby?) with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So here is an image of what I have and what I want to get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkaYO.jpg

Basically Those are SUMIF formulas in excel, I would like to recreate that in python, I was trying with pandas groupby().sum() function but I have no clue how to groupby on 2 headers like this, and then how to order the data.

Original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Group': {0: 'Name', 1: 20201001, 2: 20201002, 3: 20201003, 4: 20201004, 5: 20201005, 6: 20201006, 7: 20201007, 8: 20201008, 9: 20201009, 10: 20201010}, 'Credit': {0: 'Credit', 1: 65, 2: 69, 3: 92, 4: 18, 5: 58, 6: 12, 7: 31, 8: 29, 9: 12, 10: 41}, 'Equity': {0: 'Stock', 1: 92, 2: 62, 3: 54, 4: 52, 5: 14, 6: 5, 7: 14, 8: 17, 9: 54, 10: 51}, 'Equity.1': {0: 'Option', 1: 87, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 24, 5: 95, 6: 77, 7: 44, 8: 77, 9: 88, 10: 85}, 'Credit.1': {0: 'Credit', 1: 62, 2: 60, 3: 91, 4: 57, 5: 65, 6: 50, 7: 75, 8: 55, 9: 48, 10: 99}, 'Equity.2': {0: 'Option', 1: 61, 2: 91, 3: 38, 4: 3, 5: 71, 6: 51, 7: 74, 8: 41, 9: 59, 10: 31}, 'Bond': {0: 'Bond', 1: 4, 2: 62, 3: 91, 4: 66, 5: 30, 6: 51, 7: 76, 8: 6, 9: 65, 10: 73}, 'Unnamed: 7': {0: 'Stock', 1: 54, 2: 23, 3: 74, 4: 92, 5: 36, 6: 89, 7: 88, 8: 32, 9: 19, 10: 91}, 'Bond.1': {0: 'Bond', 1: 96, 2: 10, 3: 11, 4: 7, 5: 28, 6: 82, 7: 13, 8: 46, 9: 70, 10: 46}, 'Bond.2': {0: 'Bond', 1: 25, 2: 53, 3: 96, 4: 70, 5: 52, 6: 9, 7: 98, 8: 9, 9: 48, 10: 58}, 'Unnamed: 10': {0: float('nan'), 1: 63.0, 2: 80.0, 3: 17.0, 4: 21.0, 5: 30.0, 6: 78.0, 7: 23.0, 8: 31.0, 9: 72.0, 10: 65.0}} )
```

What I want at the end:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Group': {0: 20201001, 1: 20201002, 2: 20201003, 3: 20201004, 4: 20201005, 5: 20201006, 6: 20201007, 7: 20201008, 8: 20201009, 9: 20201010}, 'Credit': {0: 127, 1: 129, 2: 183, 3: 75, 4: 123, 5: 62, 6: 106, 7: 84, 8: 60, 9: 140}, 'Equity': {0: 240, 1: 183, 2: 132, 3: 79, 4: 180, 5: 133, 6: 132, 7: 135, 8: 201, 9: 167}, 'Stock': {0: 146, 1: 85, 2: 128, 3: 144, 4: 50, 5: 94, 6: 102, 7: 49, 8: 73, 9: 142}, 'Option': {0: 148, 1: 121, 2: 78, 3: 27, 4: 166, 5: 128, 6: 118, 7: 118, 8: 147, 9: 116}} )
```

Any ideas where to start on this, or anything is appreciated

Comment: your data is not properly formatted in my opinion; the last column with the NAN header, where does it go to in the final result

Comment: @sammywemmy the NAN wont go anywhere, not everything is needed
thats how its downloaded from internal work systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. First row seems to be the real headers so we first move that to column names and set the index to `Name`

```
df2 = df.rename(columns = df.loc[0]).drop(index = 0).set_index(['Name'])
```

Then we groupby by columns and sum

```
df2.groupby(df2.columns, axis=1, sort = False).sum().reset_index()
```

and we get

```
     Name       Credit  Stock   Option  Bond
0   20201001    127.0   146.0   148.0   125.0
1   20201002    129.0   85.0    121.0   125.0
2   20201003    183.0   128.0   78.0    198.0
3   20201004    75.0    144.0   27.0    143.0
4   20201005    123.0   50.0    166.0   110.0
5   20201006    62.0    94.0    128.0   142.0
6   20201007    106.0   102.0   118.0   187.0
7   20201008    84.0    49.0    118.0   61.0
8   20201009    60.0    73.0    147.0   183.0
9   20201010    140.0   142.0   116.0   177.0
```

I realise the output is not exactly what you asked for but since we cannot see your SUMIF formulas, I do not know which columns you want to aggregate

### Edit

Following up on your comment, I note that, as far as I can tell, the rules for aggregation are somewhat messy so that the same column is included in more than one output column (like `Equity.1`). I do not think there is much you can do with automation here, and you can replicate your `SUMIF` experience by directly referencing the columns you want to add. So I think the following gives you what you want

```
df = df.drop(index =0)
df2 = df[['Group']].copy()
df2['Credit'] = df['Credit'] + df['Credit.1']
df2['Equity'] = df['Equity'] + df['Equity.1']+ df['Equity.2']
df2['Stock'] = df['Equity'] + df['Unnamed: 7']
df2['Option']  = df['Equity.1'] + df['Equity.2']
df2
```

produces

```
       Group    Credit    Equity    Stock    Option
--  --------  --------  --------  -------  --------
 1  20201001       127       240      146       148
 2  20201002       129       183       85       121
 3  20201003       183       132      128        78
 4  20201004        75        79      144        27
 5  20201005       123       180       50       166
 6  20201006        62       133       94       128
 7  20201007       106       132      102       118
 8  20201008        84       135       49       118
 9  20201009        60       201       73       147
10  20201010       140       167      142       116
```

This also gives you control over which columns to include in the final output

If you want this more automated than you need to do something about labels of your columns, as you would want a unique label for a set of columns you want to aggregate. If the same input column is used in more than one calculation it is probably easiest to just duplicate it with the right labels

Comment: Ah sorrry, The SUMIF for Credit and Equity SUMs up the Credits and Equity in the first row, while the option and bond sums up the options and bonds values in the 2. row
The values you have is correct, I just don't get it why is Equity not included when there is nothing in the code which would exclude it? And how can I exclude one category? Like in the real dataset there are 20-30, and I only need like 10 of them

Comment: Thanks a lot! By a column is being used for more than 1 output do you mean the numbers next to the date?

Also I need to do this in python to follow it up and create some dynamic tables, othwerise copying the dataset into an excel already has it automated but the file is too big/slow and some parts need to be more dynamic which is easier in python than excel

Comment: well good luck! What I meant are the numbers in `Equity.1` column feed into both `Equity` output and `Option` output, so using `groupby` is tricky -- better just be explicit about how you calculate columns as my second part of the answer shows

Comment: Ohh, I see @piterbarg well thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it